# Implementation issue with merge sort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I used the same algorithm in **Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition** but it is not working very well, its sorts only the first 4 numbers in the array.

#### code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sortArr(int *nums, int arrSize) {
    // nums[start...end]
    // nums[start...mid]  n1
    // nums[mid+1...end]  n2
    int start, mid, end;
    start = 0;
    end = arrSize-1;
    mid = (end + start) / 2;
    int n1, n2;
    n1 = mid - start + 1;
    n2 = end - mid;
    int l[n1], r[n2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        l[i] = nums[start + i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        r[i] = nums[mid + 1 + i];
    }

    int i, j;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (int k = start; k < arrSize; k++) {
        if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
            nums[k] = l[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            nums[k] = r[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugger.......

Comment: Without looking at the code or the book: check array indexing! In pseudocode it often starts at 1, in C at 0.

Comment: I used the starting index in 0 and changed other  index to work with the index 0 instead of 1

Comment: For mergesort, you need to sort the two halves before merging. And it's not your problem yet, but using a VLA for the two halves will only work for small arrays

Comment: Also your merge is wrong (it produces out-of-range reads) in the case when one of the two halves is used up. The algorithm in the book adds +infinity to both halves to prevent this, although this is not how I'd actually write it in C.

Comment: but there is no infinity in c, how I can do that.

Comment: You have kind of implemented MERGE from the book, which is only a part of mergesort (which is defined on p34).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few problems with your code, including the fact that you've only implemented MERGE from the book (a subroutine for MERGESORT), and the book uses a trick of appending +infinity to the "halves" of the array to avoid having code that handles when one of the halves is used up when merging. You've not included that trick (eg: by appending `INT_MAX` to L and R and requiring that the original array didn't include that value), but you haven't replaced it with anything so your code can easily read out of bounds when merging.

Here's a working version based on the book algorithms. Compared to the code in the question, it also avoids the VLAs (variable length arrays) which are likely to fail on large input arrays using a one-time `malloc`-ed buffer, and uses the more correct `size_t` for array indexes.

The code adds some extra tests in the `if` statement for `li` and `ri` when merging which is a different way than the book's +infinity trick, and works better in C.

The top-level function MERGESORT returns 1 if successful, and 0 if unsuccessful (which can happen if `malloc` fails). Assertions are used to check assumptions about the various indexes and sizes -- these should fail only if there's a bug in the code and can be compiled out.

It runs on a random array of a configurable size (currently 1234), and prints out `ok` or `failed` at the end depending whether the array is actually sorted. (Note: `rand` is normally to be avoided because it's usually a poor supply of random numbers, but it's fine here).

Note this code is carefully written, but it's still not very well tested so you may find bugs!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void MERGE(int *nums, int *buffer, size_t start, size_t mid, size_t end) {
    size_t n1 = mid - start + 1;
    size_t n2 = end - mid;
    assert(n1 > 0);
    assert(n2 > 0);
    memcpy(buffer, nums + start, (end - start + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int *L = buffer;
    int *R = buffer + n1;
    size_t li = 0, ri = 0;
    for (size_t i = start; i <= end; i++ ){
        if (li < n1 && (ri == n2 || L[li] <= R[ri])) {
            assert(li < n1);
            nums[i] = L[li++];
        } else {
            assert(ri < n2);
            nums[i] = R[ri++];
        }
    }
}

void MERGESORT0(int *nums, int *buffer, size_t start, size_t end) {
    if (end == start) return;
    size_t mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    MERGESORT0(nums, buffer, start, mid);
    MERGESORT0(nums, buffer, mid+1, end);
    MERGE(nums, buffer, start, mid, end);
}

int MERGESORT(int *nums, size_t size) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    if (!buffer) return 0;
    MERGESORT0(nums, buffer, 0, size-1);
    free(buffer);
    return 1;
}

#define N 1234
int main(){
    int arr[N];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
    size_t arrsize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("before sorting: \n");
    for(size_t i=0; i<arrsize; i++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    if (!MERGESORT(arr, arrsize)) {
        printf("failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("after sorting: \n");
    int failed = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<arrsize; i++){
        if (i > 0 && arr[i] < arr[i-1]) failed = 1;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n", failed ? "failed" : "ok");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the books implementation of top down merge sort is used as an example of divide and conquer algorithm. Almost all library implementations of a stable sort are a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort, such as timsort.

Answer (score 0):

Add this print command to the final loop: `printf("%d %d %d\n", k, i, j);`

`n1 = n2 = 4`, so both arrays have values only up to index 3. Yet in the final loop, you run `i` from 0 to 6. This cannot work.

You can add more print commands, run the algorithm with pen and paper, and hopefully find the place where it went wrong.

Comment: i understand now that's the last index in l[i] is i = 3 but in the loop its go to i=6 so that's totally wrong

Comment: `arrSize` is 8, and the last loop correctly goes from 0 (inclusive) to 8 (exclusive).

Comment: @PaulHankin That is the range for `k`, not `i`.

Comment: this book its driving me crazy, the insertion sort algorithm worked fine, but this...  i think i should change to other algo books